# is there any tips or function for creating sign in with google in the flutter web application?

Tags: flutter, function, google-api, google-signin

I'm working on a flutter web application for my graduation project and one of the the project requires is sign in with google account and I have tried a lot of ways to apply it but i always failed this is my code

```
Future<void> _googleSignIn() async {
    final googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
    final googleAccount = await googleSignIn.signIn();
    if(googleAccount != null) {
      final googleAuth = await googleAccount.authentication;
      if(googleAuth.accessToken != null && googleAuth.idToken != null) {
        try{
          await _auth.signInWithCredential(
            GoogleAuthProvider.credential(idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
            accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken)
          );
          Navigator.pushNamed(context, PrincipalPage.id);
        } on FirebaseException catch (e){
          showDialog(
              context: context,
              builder: (context) {
                return AlertDialog(
                  content: Text(
                    e.toString(),
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.red
                    ),),
                );
              }
          );
        }
      }
      }
  }
```

the error that appeared was [image: the error],so if anyone help me to solve this error or how to create this function i will be very thankful

i tried to make the google sign in function in my web application for the localhost in different ways and functions but i always failed

Answer (score 0):

I think the message is quite clear, you need to set the origin. Google uses localhost port 5000 as standard so try using that so it will be easy for google to understand, in your launch.json in .vscode dir:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Flutter",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart",
            "args": [
                "--web-hostname",
                "localhost",
                "--web-port",
                "5000"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I would recommend using firebase if you want to make it easy for yourself though

Comment: the same error has appeared again, by the way i don't have a json file called launch. the only json file i have called manifest.json

Comment: then create a file called launch.json in the .vscode dir, it's just settings to choose the port and since google auth has that port as standard you need to specify it in order for it to work for flutter web https://sarunw.com/posts/how-to-run-flutter-app-with-arguments-in-vscode-with-launch-configuration/?utm_content=cmp-true

Comment: that is the problem that i'm working on Andrios studio not vscode

Comment: cmon man you can google the settings for android studio instead if you know what to do, you need to update the run/debug config for the web to use another port

https://developer.android.com/studio/run/rundebugconfig